# Year 2103 problem in Brasero

Tags: brasero

I'm evaluating Brasero to find a replacement for CD/DVD Creator which has a terrible user interface.  When I burn my tar file to a Brasero "Data project" the program seems to create a deliberately ambiguous date in a directory name.  For example the directory is called "Data disc (03 Oct 11)".  How can I burn my tar file without having it go into a DVD directory?

**Edit**  @brunopereira81 says that there is no actual DVD directory being created and he is correct.  However, gnome and Nautilus will see a linux path containing the ambiguous name even though that name is not a DVD directory.  As was suggested it is some sort of mount point.  I think it is a virtual device name that appears to browse like a linux directory.

Comment: Cannot understand the 2103 in the title

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure that it is not just the mount point or the volume (disc) name???

If this is what you mean (where my tab is at the moment) you can delete that text and insert one that fits you better as a disc name (ie: "MP3Collection").

[image]

I dont believe that brasero creates a folder if you are trying only to only add one file to it.

Have a look [here](http://www.addictivetips.com/ubuntu-linux-tips/use-brasero-to-burn-cddvd-in-ubuntu-linux/) for a simple guide and if that is not your problem include a screenshot of what you are experiencing.

Comment: Even if you put a name for your disc there on the box the file that you burn will still be on the root of the disc unless you specify / create a folder inside the disc.

Comment: You are correct.  If you leave the default then the path becomes /media/"Data disc (03 Oct 11)" and gnome labels it "Data disc (03 Oct 11)".  If you delete the text then the path is /media/disk and gnome calls it "DVD+R Disc" - an inconsistency (spelling) within an inconsistency, how nice.  Either way, there is no DVD directory and we now know how to get rid of the ambiguous date.

Answer (score 0):

Todays date is 03 October 2011. Since it is unlikely that you'll still use that CD in 2111, they figure it is unnecessary to specify the century, and it becomes 03 Oct 11. But you are right; if you wait one century and then burn the same disk again, it will get the same name, and that will be a problem.

But if that becomes a problem in reality, then you really do have other problems that will not be remedied by a different date format. :)

Comment: Doesn't relate to user problem, read question again.

Comment: If it does not, then heading of question needs correction.

Comment: Nobody is going to use this disk a hundred years from now but it will be used in 2103 and that's why the heading is good.